# for elem, count in other.items(): AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'items' error

Tags: python, nltk, n-gram, trigram

I'm new to python and need help with NLTK language modeling.

I'm trying to generate the setence starting with "he said" using trigram model but get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\\PycharmProjects\main.py", line 72, in <module>
    d[a, b] += freq_tri[a, b, c]
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\collections\__init__.py", line 904, in __iadd__
    for elem, count in other.items():
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'items'
```

The entire code is here:

```
# imports
import string
import random
import nltk

nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('stopwords')
nltk.download('reuters')
from nltk.corpus import reuters, stopwords
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
from nltk import FreqDist, ngrams

# input the reuters sentences
sents = reuters.sents()

# write the removal characters such as : Stopwords and punctuation
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
string.punctuation = string.punctuation + '"' + '"' + '-' + '''+''' + '—'
string.punctuation
removal_list = list(stop_words) + list(string.punctuation) + ['lt', 'rt']
removal_list

# generate unigrams bigrams trigrams
unigram = []
bigram = []
trigram = []
fourgram = []
tokenized_text = []

for sentence in sents:
    sentence = list(map(lambda x: x.lower(), sentence))
for word in sentence:
    if word == '.':
        sentence.remove(word)
    else:
        unigram.append(word)

tokenized_text.append(sentence)
bigram.extend(list(ngrams(sentence, 2, pad_left=True, pad_right=True)))
trigram.extend(list(ngrams(sentence, 3, pad_left=True, pad_right=True)))
fourgram.extend(list(ngrams(sentence, 4, pad_left=True, pad_right=True)))

# remove the n-grams with removable words
def remove_stopwords(x):
    y = []
    for pair in x:
        count = 0
        for word in pair:
            if word in removal_list:
                count = count or 0
            else:
                count = count or 1
        if (count == 1):
            y.append(pair)
    return (y)


unigram = remove_stopwords(unigram)
bigram = remove_stopwords(bigram)
trigram = remove_stopwords(trigram)
fourgram = remove_stopwords(fourgram)

# generate frequency of n-grams
freq_bi = FreqDist(bigram)
freq_tri = FreqDist(trigram)
freq_four = FreqDist(fourgram)

d = defaultdict(Counter)

for a, b, c in freq_tri:
    if (a != None and b != None):
        d[a, b] += freq_tri[a, b, c]

# Next word prediction
s = ''


def pick_word(counter):
    "Chooses a random element."
    return random.choice(list(counter.elements()))


prefix = "he", "said"
print(" ".join(prefix))
s = " ".join(prefix)
for i in range(19):
    suffix = pick_word(d[prefix])
    s = s + ' ' + suffix
    print(s)
    prefix = prefix[1], suffix
```

I tried changing the for loop to the following

```
for a, b, c in freq_tri.items():
    if (a != None and b != None):
        d[a, b] += freq_tri[a, b, c]
```

Expecting to get the items from the freq_tri list but got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\main.py", line 70, in <module>
    for a, b, c in freq_tri.items():
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

Which to be honest I don't quite understand why it returns 2 values if using items()

Please push me to the right direction I don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: The first error means you're passing an integer where a dictionary is expected. What does `None` have to do with it?

Comment: `dict.items()` returns a sequence of `key/value` pairs. So `a` is the key, `b` is the value -- what do you expect to go into `c`?

Comment: i did not understand the code. but I am sure this will help you. try this inside your for loop. `print(freq_tri[a, b, c])` this gives an integer. That may not be what you expected.

Comment: @Barmar ok, i get why dict.items() doesn't work and I get what it's complaining about now. My intention was to initialize the dictionary[a, b] to the values from freq_tri. It should be three words so therefore its a, b, c. I'm guessing what I'm doing instead is passing by the index of it instead of the value?